# problemas con un procedimiento almacenado con parametro timestamp en postgresql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

tengo un error en postgresql con un PA pero no se donde esta el error mi codigo es el siguiente.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertar_sumistra(id_persona int, id_medicamento_hora int, fecha timestamp)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO suministra(id_persona, id_medicamento_hora, fecha) VALUES(id_persona, id_medicamento_hora, fecha);
END; $$
```

cuando llamo al procedimiento me vota el siguiente error.

```
CALL  insertar_suministra(1, 1, NOW());
```

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: procedure insertar_suministra(integer, integer, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
> Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Position: 8

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la [documentación de PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-datetime.html), la función `now()` devuelve un tipo de datos **timestamp with time zone** y tú has definido el tercer argumento como **timestamp** y simple. Eso es lo que te está indicando el error.

Dado que el campo fecha de la tabla también lo habrás definido como timestamp simple o without timezone, el cambio más fácil sería invocar al procedimiento almacenado con otra función: **LOCALTIMESTAMP**.

Dentro de un CALL no estoy seguro de si tienes que invocarla

```
CALL  insertar_suministra(1, 1, LOCALTIMESTAMP);
```

o

```
CALL  insertar_suministra(1, 1, LOCALTIMESTAMP(0));
```

Answer (score -1):

Por lo que veo tienes un error solo en el nombre al procedimiento al que llamas.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE **insertar_sumistra**

tu llamas a

CALL  **insertar_suministra**(1, 1, NOW());

Comment: eso puse solo que stack overflow lo corrigio asi, no se por que.